# C++ constructor: expected identifier before numeric constant

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a game in c++ with SDL and I've encountered a problem.
I have a Bat class and a Game class.
When I'm trying to create a bat object and call the constructor I get the following error:

> "error: expected identifier before numeric constant"

Here are the source files:

**Game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "SDL.h"
#include "Bat.h"

class Game
{
    public:
        Game();
        Bat bat(0, 0);
    private:
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

**Bat.h**

```
#ifndef BAT_H
#define BAT_H

class Bat
{
    public:
        Bat(int x, int y);
        int getX() {return x;}
        int getY() {return y;}
    private:
        int x, y;
};

#endif // BAT_H
```

**Bat.cpp**

```
#include "Bat.h"

Bat::Bat(int x, int y)
{
}
```

Comment: You can't allocate the `Bat` object in the class declaration. You'll have to do it in a function, like the `Game` constructor. And you're not saving the `x` and `y` you're passing into the `Bat` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to write

```
class Game
{
    public:
        Game() : bat(0, 0) {} // <<< or move that definition to your .cpp file
    private:
        Bat bat; // << you can't initialize the member here.
};
```

??

Comment: yes, thank you. that solved it

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a member variable `bat` initialized with `0,0` try this:

```
class Game
{
    public:
        Game();

    private:
        Bat bat;
};

Game::Game() : bat(0, 0){
}
```

Comment: yes, I solved it, thank you!